# Seasoning on Magnalite anodized aluminum fry pans needs to be removed and re-done, what is process?

Tags: maintenance, aluminum-cookware

I bought a set of three Magnalite anodized fry pans(used) and was told they needed to be cleaned out and re-seasoned. What would be the best way to remove the old seasoning?

Comment: Are you sure this is anodized aluminum?  Anodized aluminum pans are not normally seasoned.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ From [here](http://www.ebay.com/gds/MAGNALITE-PROFESSIONAL-COOKWARE-LEGEND-OR-MYTH/10000000007573558/g.html): _"1. Any Magnalite Professional pan which is used for sauteeing or frying should be pre-seasoned when new and never cleaned with abrasive cleaners of any kind."_

Comment: Ebay?  Wow.   My experience with anodized aluminum is with Calphalon, which definitely does not need to be seasoned.

Answer (score 0):

Clean with hot soapy water (Dawn liquid or equivalent) with a plastic bristle brush. I use a fingernail brush from an auto parts store. Rinse thouroughly. Rinse again. Towel dry. Shake remaining water off. Put on stove low heat to dry completely. Gradually increase heat to warm pan. Add 2-3 tablespoons of oil. Not olive oil it will burn. I use vegetable oil for omelette pans and sauce pans. For frying I would go with Canola oil.

Heat pan and oil to about 350-400 F (175-200 C) Surface Temperature for frying pans or high heat pans. Remove from heat, soak up excess oil with clean paper towels. Get a few fresh paper towels and wipe in circles and coat edges and sides of pan with residual oil on paper towels. Allow pan to cool to room temp. You're done!

Comment: The question was how to remove the existing coating, not on how to season a new pan.

Answer (score -3):

If you mean that the anodization has chipped and you have bare metal showing through, the best way to remove the remaining anodization is by sandpaper and lots of time/ effort (aluminum oxide, a.k.a. corundum/ ruby/ sapphire, is one of the compounds used in sandpaper, so it's sort of like grinding a diamond with another diamond). You could also likely dissolve it with concentrated acids or alkali, but these may also destroy the pan in the process, and I do not know that I would want to do that to cookware.

The most challenging problem lies in how to put the anodization back on (very controlled re-oxidation of the surface), without a large vat of hazardous chemicals or investing more money than the pan is worth having it commercially re-anodized.

Comment: There is absolutely no *sane* reason to want to remove the anodization layer, and even if you could try to abrade it away, it is so much harder than the normal metal beneath that anything you could use to sand the anodization would absolutely shred the normal metal, destroying the surface of the pan.

Comment: Agreed, the remaining anodized coating is harder than the base metal, but the question was how to remove the coating and "re-season". From a technical standpoint this is a correct answer.